# How do I print QStringListModel content?

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, qprinter, qstringlistmodel

I need to print the content of a QStringListModel to a printer, in 'void MainWindow::on_pbImprime_clicked()' It's printing any Qstring with no problems, but I don't know how to put the data of QStringListModel to my QString text, anyone have an idea?

Here is my code:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    model = new QStringListModel(this);

    ui->lbItens->setModel(model);

    ui->lbItens->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::AnyKeyPressed |
                               QAbstractItemView::DoubleClicked);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pbAdd_clicked()
{
    int row = model->rowCount();

    model->insertRows(row,1);

    QModelIndex index = model->index(row);

    ui->lbItens->setCurrentIndex(index);
    ui->lbItens->edit(index);
}

void MainWindow::on_pbRemove_clicked()
{
    model->removeRows(ui->lbItens->currentIndex().row(),1);
}

void MainWindow::on_pbImprime_clicked()
{
        QPrinter printer;

        QPainter p(&printer);
        int x_pos = 20;
        int y_pos = 20;

        int row = model->rowCount();
        int i;

        for(i=0; i<row; i++){
            QString text = ;
            p.drawText(x_pos, y_pos, text);
            y_pos += p.fontMetrics().height();
        }
}
```

Sorry for my bad english and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get `QStringList` from your model:

```
QStringList list = model->stringList();
```

From `QStringList` get your `QString` using `join()`:

```
QString str = list.join(" ");
```

In [join](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringlist.html#join) you may choose separator you need.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can try this

```
void MainWindow::on_pbImprime_clicked()
{
    QPrinter printer;

    ...

    for(i=0; i<row; i++){
        QString text = model->data(model->index(row, 0)).toString();
        p.drawText(x_pos, y_pos, text);
        y_pos += p.fontMetrics().height();
    }
}
```

As a matter of fact, 
QVariant QAbstractItemModel::data(const QModelIndex & index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const
is the prefered way to get data out of model.